# Elasticsearch - I want to search for exact birthday that a user search for (eg. 03221989) and the upcoming birthdays

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a Birthday date-field (format: MMddyyyy||MMdd) in my index. I want to search for exact birthday that a user search for (eg. 03221989) and the upcoming birthdays. I am able to get the exact birthday. But for upcoming birthdays, i tried:

- Range query - "gte" : "now" -> it won't work as now will also have a year field and I want to find 03221989 type Birthdays as well
- Range query - "gte" : "03221989" -> with this i am able to sort the records in ascending order of Month

In my index, I have 3 records:

```
"Birthday": "03221979"
"Birthday": "05271988"
"Birthday": "04161990"
```

I want the elasticsearch query to return me in ascending order of month irrespective of year. Return data should be:

```
"Birthday": "03221979"
"Birthday": "04161990"
"Birthday": "05271988"
```

Comment: Please provide a sample document and the mapping

Answer (score 0):

You can use range query with formate specifying in it.

```
GET _search
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "dateofbirth": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "dateofbirth": {
        "gte": "03221989",
        "format": "MMddyyyy||yyyy||MMdd"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Something like this.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response.. Actually I have tried this, but it's not helping in getting the data in ascending order. 
"Birthday": "03221979"
"Birthday": "01221978"
"Birthday": "04161990"
"Birthday": "05271988"
This is the query result which is not in ascending order of month.

Comment: you are very welcome let me know if this sorts your issue.

Comment: but it's not helping in getting the data in ascending order. "Birthday": "03221979" "Birthday": "01221978" "Birthday": "04161990" "Birthday": "05271988" This is the query result which is not in ascending order of month.

Comment: @ArpanSahoo PLease check updated answer added sorting in there.

Comment: Already added.. But there is a problem. Suppose the records in Elasticsearch are "Birthday": "03221979" "Birthday": "12221978" "Birthday": "01161990" And i am searching for  "Birthday": "03221979", then the above query output is only "Birthday": "03221979"  "Birthday": "12221978"... after 12(i.e. December) it doesn't show from Jan again(i.e. "Birthday": "01161990" - this record)

Comment: then you need to put some pieces of data i here so this can be checked